# Missing MapBox Token when using Apache Superset with Docker

Tags: python, docker, mapbox, apache-superset

I've installed Apache Superset according to [this](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose) official manual. I can create plots, connect to databases etc. without any problems, only if I want to plot *latitude* and *longitude* data with a **mapbox** or **deck.gl** plots, I get this warning and can't see any maps:

> NO_TOKEN_WARNING
> For information on setting up your basemap, read
> Note on Map Tokens

I have a MapBox-Api-Key (lets say XXYYZZ) and followed instructions where I created a `superset_config.py` file in the home folder of the server where superset is running. This is the code I used:

## Entries in `.bashrc`

export SUPERSET_HOME=/home/maximus/envs/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset
export SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/.superset/superset_config.py
export PYTHONPATH=/home/maximus/envs/superset/bin/python:/home/maximus/.superset:$PYTHONPATH

#### Created `superset_confiy.py` in `.superset`

**path: `$ ~/.superset/superset_config.py`**

with following code

```py
#---------------------------------------------------------
# Superset specific config
#---------------------------------------------------------
ROW_LIMIT = 50000

MAPBOX_API_KEY = 'XXYYZZ'
```

As I'm using docker, I thought maybe I need to to the same within the main docker container of superset (`superset_app`) but it still does not work.

My server runs on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Anyone any ideas on how to solve this problem with docker, superset and mapbox?

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by adding my mapbox token (*XXYYZZ*) to the docker environment file which is used by *docker-compose*.

This is what I did in detail:

- As *superset* runs on my server I connected via ssh
- Stop superset with `docker-compose down`
- `cd` into the `docker` folder within the folder where the `docker-compose` files is --> `cd superset/docker`
- I was running the *non-dev* version with docker-compose, therefore I opened the `.env-non-dev` file with *nano*. If you run the "normal" version just edit the `.env` file instead.

> Comment: I'm not sure if this is the supposed way, but apparently you can edit the environmental parameters.

- I added my *Mapbox* Key (MAPBOX_API_KEY = "XXYYZZ")
- Finally just start superset again with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up -d` or `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` respectively.

Thats all, I can now see the maps when opening the *deck.gl* sample dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation and a youtube video tutorial seem outdated.
For the most recent release:
clone the superset repo;
add the MAPBOX_API_KEY to the superset/config.py or docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config.py;
then docker-compose up solved the problem